# Implement Array on Form Field Using Index and Spread Operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms

I want to implement a form that can handle array data with dynamic field. I build that app with TypeScript.

But it gave me an `error`:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ name: string; email: string; }'.ts(7053)
```

I've searched google about that. I found a source that similar of my problem.

This is the part of code

```
const [formValues, setFormValues] = React.useState([{ name: "", email: "" }]);

  let handleChangeForm = (i: any, e: any) => {
    let newFormValues = [...formValues];
    newFormValues[i][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    setFormValues(newFormValues);
  };
```

This is a link of that source:
https://bapunawarsaddam.medium.com/add-and-remove-form-fields-dynamically-using-react-and-react-hooks-3b033c3c0bf5

Comment: try change "i' & "e" type to string in `handleChangeForm` like: `(i: string, e: { name: string, email : string})`

Comment: @kian it still give me error: in i, `(Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.)` and target: `(Property 'target' does not exist on type '{ name: string; email: string; }'.)`

Comment: so try this: `(i: number, e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)`

Comment: @kian a new error generated: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ name: string; email: string; }'.`
`No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ name: string; email: string; }'.`

Answer (score 0):

I change the code to solve a problem:

```
let handleChangeForm = (i: any, e: any) => {
    setFormValues(([i][e.target.name] = e.target.value));
};
```